# ajax, multiple add to cart buttons: why does only first one work?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and trying to get multiple add to cart buttons working on my e-commerce site.

Currently only the first one works asynchronously. The other three will run the additemtocart.php code (add item to cart) but the page reloads and a "?" is tacked on to the end of the url, like a GET request??

I'd like to stick with vanilla js if possible.  thank you for any help.

```
<h1>Multiple add to cart buttons vanilla js</h1>
<form id="A2Cform">
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart" onClick = "A2Cdbq('28753')">
</form>

<form id="A2Cform">
<input type="submit" value="add to cart" onClick = "A2Cdbq('28754')">
</form>

<form id="A2Cform">
<input type="submit" value="add to cart" onClick = "A2Cdbq('28755')">
</form>

<form id="A2Cform">
<input type="submit" value="add to cart" onClick = "A2Cdbq('28756')">
</form>

<div id="addtocartMsg"> </div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("A2Cform").addEventListener("submit", function(event){event.preventDefault()});

    function A2Cdbq(prodid){//add item to the cart table

        var params = "product_id="+prodid;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'additemtocart.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);

            document.getElementById('addtocartMsg').innerHTML = 'Item added to cart.';

            }
        }
        xhr.send(params);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Browsers are very lenient and will try to understand what you mean even if you mess up your HTML horribly, but ID should uniquely identify an element, and 2) `document.getElementById` only returns *one element*. This means only the first of your forms gets an event handler that prevents the default submit action, so the other forms will do what forms normally do: submit (using the default GET method, and the default action being the current URL).

One correct way to do this would be to change your `id` into another attribute, such as `class`. Then you can use `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll` to grab multiple elements, iterate over them and attach an event listener to each one.

Alternately, you can attach an event listener only once, to a common ancestor of those elements, and in the handler check if the event target had the correct class.

The first approach is somewhat simpler.

Also, using `onclick` in this manner is discouraged. It would be better if the handler you are attaching actually did the work, without having to write JavaScript inside HTML. But if you are committed to this, then you don't need the submit handler at all, just make sure to return `false` from the `onclick`.

The first approach, a bit more elaborated. Don't actually need the class, we will use a data attribute to carry the product ID, and we can find the buttons based on its presence, using the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Note that since there is no normal submission going on we don't actually need a form, just a button:

```
<input type="button" value="add to cart" data-prod="28755"/>
```

and in JavaScript:

```
function A2Cdbq(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const prodid = evt.target.getAttribute("data-prod");
  // ....
}

for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("[data-prod]")) {
  element.addEventListener("click", A2Cdbq);
}
```